# How to prevent this JOIN query from doing an almost full table scan

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

The dataset in items  contains about 4.4 million rows

`updated` and `created` are indexed individually on each table

```
EXPLAIN SELECT i.id, j.id 
    FROM jobs j 
JOIN items i ON j.items_id = i.id 
WHERE j.updated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) 
    OR j.created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) 
    OR i.updated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE);
```

Here is what I get:

```
1   SIMPLE  i   index   PRIMARY,updated_idx                     updated_idx       5     NULL            4168353    Using index
1   SIMPLE  j   ref     items_id_idx,updated_idx,created_idx    items_id_idx      9      my_db.i.id     1          Using where
```

As you can see the items, while using `updated_idx`, still runs close to a full table scan.

Why is this happening, and is there anyway I can avoid this?

Also tried this, but it performs worse:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT i.id, j.id 
    FROM jobs j 
WHERE j.updated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)
    OR j.created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) 
    OR j.items_id IN 
         (SELECT i.id FROM items i WHERE i.updated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySql does not optimize or conditions in the where criteria too well. Rewrite your query as 3 separate selects joined with union. This way each query can utilise the appropriate indexes:

```
SELECT i.id, j.id 
    FROM jobs j 
JOIN items i ON j.items_id = i.id 
WHERE j.updated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)
UNION DISTINCT  
SELECT i.id, j.id 
    FROM jobs j 
JOIN items i ON j.items_id = i.id 
WHERE j.created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) 
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT i.id, j.id 
    FROM jobs j 
JOIN items i ON j.items_id = i.id 
WHERE i.updated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE);
```

Comment: Well that was easier than I thought it would be. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this requires 3 indexes, which the OP seemed to have.